# I2c commands not working in U-boot

Tags: embedded-linux, u-boot

Am trying to validate I2c communication on xilinx zynq zc702 evaluation board in u-boot(as a part of board bring up) with i2c commands but i observed the logs in minicom console saying i2c command not found. Please can i know how to fix this type of issue and how to make the commands work in u-boot

Comment: If the commands are *"not found"*, that that simply means that the U-Boot that you're using was configured and built without those commands.  You are going to have to reconfigure and then recompile U-Boot.

Comment: You can enable I2C commands by enabling `Command line interface > Device access commands > i2c`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you didn't enable I2C command in your u-boot configuration and hence it not compile as part of your u-boot.

**CONFIG_CMD_I2C=y** should be **=y**, check and recompile your u-boot source